# Why ZeroMQ is not using its internal threads for waiting (on receive / send)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, zeromq

From the source code it is apparent that each ZeroMQ Socket create its own internal thread (weather your main app is multi-threaded or not), when you make the call `zsocket_new`.

Those internal threads are running a loop doing `select (0, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, timeout ? &tv : NULL)` (line 167--173, select.cpp).

Now, what I do not understand is, despite the availability of those internal threads, why is that methods such as `zmq_msg_recv` behave as blocking calls, making your main thread block?

For example, consider this below code

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new();
void *router = zsocket_new(ctx, ZMQ_ROUTER);

int rc = zsocket_bind(router, "tcp://*:8080");
zframe_t *handle = zframe_recv(router);
```

It blocks on `zframe_recv` on your calling thread, waiting at line 207--212 of signaler.cpp, doing `int rc = select (0, &fds, NULL, NULL, timeout_ >= 0 ? &timeout : NULL)`

In other words, for a single ZMQ-socket you have two threads doing two select() operations!!

If you want to make `zframe_recv` asynchronous you would have to start your-own thread and do polling or blocking inside that thread.

The question is - why is that ZMQ not using these internal threads for both selects, instead of forcing you to create another thread just to read/write the data??

If only it could use the internal thread appropriately it could become a very good actor model - any ideas why it is not doing it?

Comment: `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` makes you receive [non blocking](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv).

Comment: Thanks Theolodis. The question, unfortunately, is not about 'making it not block' as much as it is about making it 'asynchronous'. Sure `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` makes it `not block` - but it does not make it asynchronous (meaning, if you want to read 100 messages, you would still need to write a loop, thus essentially blocking your own thread or make your messages wait or create another dedicated thread to do the looping). Contrast it with offloading the looping (blocking or non-blocking) to the internal thread, which is by default created by ZMQ. That is asynchronous, a pure actor model.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, what I do not understand is, despite the availability of those internal threads, why is that methods such as zmq_msg_recv behave as blocking calls, making your main thread block?

ZMQ encourages a network with a collection of single-threaded nodes. Each node has a collection of sockets that it uses to communicate with other nodes. The ZMQ contexts on nodes manage the actual transport of messages across wires and have their own collection of threads for doing that, but your node logic is encouraged to be single threaded.

This could be described as "reactive programming."  Inbound messages are events, and you respond to those by sending outbound messages. When you call `zmq_msg_recv` or `zmq_poll`, the meaning is "wait for the next event" and is appropriately blocking.

If you find you cannot implement your desired node logic with a single-threaded solution, consider reviewing your design to make sure that your 3-threaded node should not instead be 3 single-threaded nodes.